# Is there a way Coldfusion can send all errors to a specific email?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have:

Server Details
Server Product  ColdFusion
Version  9,0,1,274733
Edition  Standard
Operating System  Windows Server 2008
OS Version  6.0
Adobe Driver Version  4.0 (Build 0005)
Is it possible that I can receive all the errors that happen on coldfusion to a specific email?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to add a cferror to every page you can add a onError method to your application.cfc this function will be called whenever any page has an error.

```
 <cffunction name="onError">
    <!--- The onError method gets two arguments:
    An exception structure, which is identical to a cfcatch variable.
    The name of the Application.cfc method, if any, in which the error
    happened. --->
    <cfargument name="Except" required="true"/>
    <cfargument type="String" name = "EventName" required="true"/>
     error handling goes here 
</cffunction>
```

I also saw you had a question where you were worried about the mail server not working. If you are worried that you will not be able to receive emails about your errors you can log them to a file.

```
<!--- Log all errors in an application-specific log file. --->
<cflog file="filename" type="error" text="Event Name: #Eventname#" >
<cflog file="filename" type="error" text="Message: #except.message#">
```

Comment: Nice answer. Exactly what I would have said. @user3591637 Just to add to this, if you are worried about cfmail a UI for logs can be found in CFAdmin, under Debugging and Logging to check error logs too.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [cferror](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cferror) tag.  It is exactly what you need.

You can put `cferror` in the Application.cfm file, if you are not using Application.cfc, and it will work on every page.

```
<cferror type="exception" 
      template="/error.cfm" 
      mailto="your@email.com" 
      exception="any">
```

This is the recommended way to email notification of errors pre CFMX7.  It still works in CFMX7 and after but best practice suggests the use the onError() method of Application.cfc

[wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/onError](http://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/onError)

Comment: i actually got something that sends me an email for a error but for a specific page, i was just wondering if i can do something in coldfusion that i dont have to put cferror on every page?

Comment: Take a look at the onError() method of Application.cfc: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/onError

Comment: Hey Randy.  My vote put your reputation over 100.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: TBH I think suggesting using `<cferror>` on versions of ColdFusion after CFMX6 is poor advice. One should be using Application.cfc and `onError()`, as @CarlVonStetten suggests.